# Python symbol comparison

Tags: python

I have  `st = 'aaaabbсaa'`. My task is if in the string characters repeat then I must write the character plus a number counting the repeats.

My code (but it doesn't work):

```
st = "aaaabbcaa"
cnt = 0
cnt2 = 0
cnt3 = 0

j = len(st)
i = 0


while i < j:
    if st[i] == st[i - 1]:
        cnt += 1
        print("a" + str(cnt), end="")
    elif st[i] == st[i - 1]:
        cnt2 += 1
        print("b" + str(cnt2), end="")
    elif st[i] == st[i - 1]:
        cnt3 += 1
        print("c" + str(cnt3), end="")

    i += 1
```

Sample Input 1: `aaaabbcaa`
Sample Output 1: `a4b2c1a2`
Sample Input 2: `abc`
Sample Output 2: `a1b1c1`

Comment: This is called 'run-length encoding'.

Comment: All your if/elif conditions are the same. Hint: You shouldn't need one for each different letter anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got three problems with your code.

First, as gnibbler points out, all of your `if`/`elif` conditions are the same. And you don't need a separate condition for each letter, you just need to print the variable (like `st[i]`) instead of a literal (like `"a"`).

Second, you're trying to print out the current run length for each character in the run, instead of after the entire run. So, if you get this working, instead of `a4b2c1a2` you're going to get `a1a2a3a4b1b2c1a1a2`. You need to keep track of the current run length for each character in the run, but then only print it out when you get to a *different* character.

Finally, you've got two off-by-one errors. First, when `i` starts at 0, `st[i - 1]` is `st[-1]`, which is the last character; you don't want to compare with that. Second, when `i` finally gets to `j-1` at the end, you've got a leftover run that you need to deal with.

So, the smallest change to your code is:

```
st = "aaaabbcaa"
cnt = 0

j = len(st)
i = 0

while i < j:
    if i == 0 or st[i] == st[i - 1]:
        cnt += 1
    else:
        print(st[i - 1] + str(cnt), end="")
        cnt = 1

    i += 1

print(st[i - 1] + str(cnt))
```

---

As a side note, one really easy way to improve this: `range(len(st))` gives you all the numbers from 0 up to but not including `len(st)`, so you can get rid of `j` and the manual `i` loop and just use `for i in range(len(st)):`.

But you can improve this even further by looping over an iterable of `st[i], st[i-1]` pairs; then you don't need the indexes at all. This is pretty easy with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). And then you don't need the special handling for the edges either either:

```
st = "aaaabbcaa"
cnt = 1
for current, previous in zip(st[1:]+" ", st):
    if current == previous:
        cnt += 1
    else:
        print(previous + str(cnt), end="")
        cnt = 1
```

---

I think [Matthias's `groupby` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027122/908494) is more pythonic, and simpler (there's still a lot of things you could get wrong with this, like starting with `cnt = 0`), but this should be mostly understandable to a novice out of the box. (If you don't understand the `zip(st[1:]+" ", st)`, try printing out `st[1:]`, `list(zip(st[1:], st))`, and `list(zip(st[1:]+" ", st)` and it should be clearer.)

Comment: @abarnert Please recommend to me book or materials of programming in c# or python. I want to solve my logical to do best and brain work good. Thank's.

Comment: @EldarNecefov: Honestly, I learned Python through the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and reference guide and inline help. It was a great resource in the late 90s for someone who already knew other languages like C, Perl, ML, and Smalltalk, but I doubt that's going to be much good for you. The official website has a [Getting Started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) page with links to all kinds of books and other resources, and there's a [python-tutor mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) which I think has a FAQ.

Comment: @EldarNecefov: I'm probably even less useful for C#. I mainly learned it from a "differences between C# and Java" webpage and Microsoft's "C# for C++/.NET programmers" docs, and never used it that much anyway.

Comment: @EldarNecefov: The only programming books I can definitely recommend aren't for either language you want: Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby is a great first book for anyone, then Learn You a Haskell for Great Good and The C Programming Language will expand your horizons in opposite directions, and after that you should be able to pick up any particular language pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a task for [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from itertools import groupby
data = 'aaaabbсaa'
compressed = ''.join('{}{}'.format(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(data))
print(compressed)
```

Result

```
a4b2с1a2
```

This might help to understand what's happening here.

```
data = 'aaaabbсaa'
for key, group in groupby(data):
    print(key, len(list(group)))
```

Result

```
a 4
b 2
с 1
a 2
```

Comment: exactly how I'd do it, but I included an answer that's closer to OP's attempted code for completeness.

Comment: Yes this help too, but I needed solutions without any import :) Thnaks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a silly way to go about it, but:

```
def encode(s):
    _lastch = s[0]
    out = []
    count = 0
    for ch in s:
        if ch == _lastch:
            count +=1
        else:
            out.append(_lastch + str(count))
            _lastch = ch
            count = 1
    out.append(_lastch + str(count))
    return ''.join(out)
```

Example

```
>>> st = "aaaabbcaa"
>>> encode(st)
'a4b2c1a2'
```