# Work with strings on Python . Cant find error

Tags: python

In input we getting string like

```
asdfssgAAatG
```

and output must be a compressed string with letter count. For example input

```
aabggtttf
```

must give

```
a2b1g2t3f1
```

so letter and how many times it repeated in row in output. The input

```
abc
```

must give

```
a1b1c1
```

in output. So i wrote some code for it:

```
a=str(input())+' '
count=1
b=1
r=''
for i in range (a.count('')-2):
  if a[i]==a[i+1]:
        b+=1
  else:
        count=b
        b=1
        r=r+a[i]+str(count)
if a!=' ':
    print(result=r[0:-1]+str(count))
```

For me code works flawless and when i put test input it give correct answer. But on site where i need to insert that code 'steptic.org' some of automated tests give error, and i cant complete this task. So here the question: what  wrong with this code and what input can give error here? Maybe is here some simplier way to perform this task on Python?
P.S Sry for my bad english =)
P.S Capitalization matter, test content i cant see, i tryed some test data - all worked.. , seems i just cant think out data what gives incorrect answer.

Comment: Which tests give errors? What are the error messages?

Comment: Improve your title. And regarding testing: Write some test cases yourself. And how were you supposed to handle case?

Comment: Does capitalization matter? What is the desired output for asdfssgAAatG?

Comment: for asdfssgAAatG must be a1d1f1s2g1A2a1t1G1

Comment: And i dont know what tests gives error - here only message that test 10 gived a error i cant view test content - i tryed some test input -  all worked, and i cant find data which gives and error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python symbol comparsion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026972/python-symbol-comparsion)

Comment: What if the input contains spaces? Btw, you should just `print r` in the end.

Comment: why ``str(input())``? wouldn't it be simply ``raw_input()``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not worry about case of letter: using `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_string = 'asdfssgAAatG'
>>> "".join(sorted([x+str(y) for x,y in Counter(my_string).items()],key=lambda x:my_string.index(x[0])))
'a2s3d1f1g1A2t1G1'
```

create a function and return it:

```
>>> def count_it(my_string):
...     return "".join(sorted([x+str(y) for x,y in Counter(my_string).items()],key=lambda x:my_string.index(x[0])))
... 
>>> count_it('aabggtttf')
'a2b1g2t3f1'
>>> count_it('abc')
'a1b1c1'
```

using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> "".join([ x+str(len(list(y))) for x,y in itertools.groupby('aabggtttf')])
'a2b1g2t3f1'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what tests are failing and in what ways, so I can't comment on that.

However, you could use `itertools.groupby()` to achieve the desired results:

```
In [13]: s = 'aabggtttf'

In [14]: ''.join(('%s%d' % (l, sum(1 for _ in g))) for l, g in itertools.groupby(s))
Out[14]: 'a2b1g2t3f1'
```

Here:

- `for l, g in itertools.groupby(s)` iterates over runs of identical letters;
- `'%s%d' % (l, sum(1 for _ in g)))` produces a string consisting of the letter and the length of the run.

Comment: What's with the underscore in `sum(1 for _ in g)`? Thanks, @NPE

Comment: @Tico: It's just a variable like any other. It needs to have a name, but that name is not used. Following a common convention, I name the variable `_`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python